# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined: Datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables-1.10

So I'm following the information here, http://datatables.net/examples/ajax/simple.html, just to setup a very basic datatable. I'll work on getting it exactly the way I want once that is done. Here's my code:

Table:

```
<table id='transactions' class='table table-hover'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Symbol</th>
            <th>Company Name</th>
            <th>Market</th>
            <th>Purchase Price</th>
            <th>Commission</th>
            <th>Shares</th>
            <th>Purchase Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Symbol</th>
            <th>Company Name</th>
            <th>Market</th>
            <th>Purchase Price</th>
            <th>Commission</th>
            <th>Shares</th>
            <th>Purchase Date</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
$('table#transactions').dataTable({
    ajax: url
});
```

Data (received):

```
{"data":
    [
        ["AAPL","Apple Inc.","NYSE","30.00","0.00","100","2015-02-03"],
        ["T.TO","TELUS Corporation","TSE","12.75","1.25","400","2015-02-03"],
        ["SNE","Sony Corporation","NASDAQ","42.63","2.50","50","2015-01-28"]
    ]
}
```

So the issue is I'm getting the error in the title, and I have no idea why. As far as I can tell, I've almost exactly copied the code on the example page, and copied the way the data is sent. I was hoping another set of eyes would help tell me where I went wrong.

EDIT:

I've changed the data being sent to the smallest amount of data possible, and checked the actual response from the network, and this is what I see:

```
"{\"data\":[\"AAPL\",\"Apple Inc.\",\"NYSE\",\"30.00\",\"0.00\",\"100\",\"2015-02-03\"]}"
```

Is the output of that data messing me up? I should mention I am sending this data via PHP, it was an array that I used json_encode on.

Comment: What do you mean by "getting the error in the title". What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @minion The error message is "cannot read property 'length' of undefined", which is in the title of the question.

Comment: Make sure your Javascript is in the `$(document).ready()` function.

Comment: It is, sorry, I didn't include that, didn't think it was necessary.

Comment: Exactly on what line is this error occurring? Is it occurring in the data-tables library? Also did you check that `url` is defined correctly? And are the libraries correctly included  (jQuery included first )?

Comment: I'm receiving the data, so yes, all of the libraries are correct, and the url is correct, otherwise I'd be receiving an ajax error. The line # isn't overly helpful, as I'm using the minified version, but yes, the error is coming from the DataTables library, not my own code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally figured out the answer to this and thought I would put it up for anyone in the same position as me.

DataTables states that it wants a json object, so I encoded an array in PHP using json_encode to get that. However, it turns out that sending a standard array of $data['data'][] is what it actually wants.